# Python3, converting MATLAB array code to Python version?

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, 2d, nested-lists

I have a MATLAB code that looks like this:

```
dindex =find(H2(:,1)>=2400)
H2     =H2(dindex,:);
```

I find all the rows of a 2-d array, H2, in which its 1st column is bigger than 2400.

How can this be done in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/) for this, it's a very powerful python library that makes this sort of task trivial.

[`numpy.where()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) is what you are looking for here:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.array([[2500, 1, 1, 1, 1], [2300, 1, 1, 1, 1], [2600, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
>>> arr
array([[2500,    1,    1,    1,    1],
       [2300,    1,    1,    1,    1],
       [2600,    1,    1,    1,    1]])
>>> np.where(arr[:,0] >= 2400)
(array([0, 2], dtype=int64),)
```

If you only want to keep the rows that meet this condition, you can do this with `numpy` indexing:

```
>>> arr = np.array([[2500, 1, 1, 1, 1], [2300, 1, 1, 1, 1], [2600, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
>>> arr
array([[2500,    1,    1,    1,    1],
       [2300,    1,    1,    1,    1],
       [2600,    1,    1,    1,    1]])
>>> arr = arr[np.where(arr[:,0] >= 2400)]
>>> arr
array([[2500,    1,    1,    1,    1],
       [2600,    1,    1,    1,    1]])
```

Comment: i've never used numpy before, so i am a bit confused. I want to replace the original 2-d array with only rows with its 1st column bigger than 2400. How can I do that, after your code? So, in the list 'arr', I want to remove the middle row, by using the index obtained from numpy.

Comment: Updated my answer.